# A symbol/notation for a line tangent to something?

Tags: notation, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

I was doing problems of analytical geometry, specifically things like: "Find the equation of the circumference given the line tangent to it of equation...". I was wondering, since there is a way to write down that a line is parallel to another with pure mathematical notation, is there any way that mathematicians do the same for lines tangent to another line, a parabola, a circumference, etc? That is, is there some form of notation or symbol for that?

Comment: In differential geometry it's standard to write $T_pM$ for the set of tangent *vectors* at point $p$ of the (generalized) surface $M$.

Comment: I don't think there is. If it did, it would probably (if I had to design it) be a circle with a line tangent to it, but I did not find anything in unicode of the sort.